# Anti-compact space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A space $X$ is called anti-compact if any compact subset of $X$ is finite. It is known that uncountable space with co-countable topology is an example of a $T_1$ anti-compact space that is not Hausdorff.

I am  looking for other examples. Is there any one can give me another example of an anti-compact space that is $T_1$ but not Hausdorff?

Comment: "A space X is called anti-compact if for any compact subset is finite". I don't understand. Which set is finite?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Any compact subset.

Comment: I believe the Op means "A space $X$ is anti-compact if every compact subspace of $X$ is finite".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro for any compact subset of $X$. I will edit it

Comment: @Giuseppe: In general a space $X$ is *anti-P* if the only subsets of $X$ that are *P* are those that are forced by their cardinality to be *P*. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409839/12042).

Comment: I added a small modification, it is clearer now according to me. Please revert the edit if you disagree

Comment: @lolo: *Anti-Hausdorff* isn’t a standard term; do you want $T_1$ examples that are not Hausdorff? [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/517419/12042) has a couple of nice Hausdorff example.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, I am looking for $T_1$ that are not Hausdorff.

Comment: @lolo: I just realized that you might mean something even stronger than non-Hausdorff: do you want it to have the property that there is *no* pair of points that can be separated by disjoint open sets?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: My intention is looking for $T_1$  anti-compact but non-Haudorff.  The example for such space is only uncountable space with co-countable topology. But if you can provide an example stronger than non-Hausdorff, I really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I see a couple of easy ways to build more examples.

Let $Y$ be an uncountable space with the co-countable topology, let $Z$ be a discrete space, and let $X=Z\times Y$. Clearly $X$ is $T_1$ but not Hausdorff. Suppose that $A\subseteq X$ is infinite, and for each $z\in Z$ let $A_z=A\cap\big(\{z\}\times Y\big)$. If $\{z\in Z:A_z\ne\varnothing\}$ is infinite, then $A$ is clearly not compact, so $A_z$ is infinite for some $z\in Z$. But then $A_z$ is a closed, non-compact subset of $A$, so $A$ is not compact. It follows that $X$ is anticompact. Moreover, the maximum cardinality of a family of pairwise disjoint, non-empty open sets in $X$ is $|Z|$, so for a given $Y$ we really do get different spaces when we change $|Z|$.

Alternatively, we could start with any non-discrete anticompact Hausdorff space $X$; there are three in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/517419/12042) by **bof**, and I’ll add one more that is similar to the last two in **bof**’s answer:

> Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$, and let $X=\{\mathscr{U}\}\cup\Bbb N$; then $$\tau=\wp(\Bbb N)\cup\big\{\{\mathscr{U}\}\cup U:U\in\mathscr{U}\big\}$$ is an anticompact Hausdorff space that is not discrete.

Let $p$ be any limit point of $X$, and let $q$ be a point not in $X$. Let $\mathscr{N}$ be the family of open nbhds of $p$. Let $Y=X\cup\{q\}$; the topology on $Y$ is

$$\{Y\}\cup\tau\cup\big\{\{q\}\cup(N\setminus\{p\}):N\in\mathscr{N}\big\}\;.$$

In other words, the open nbhds of $q$ are identical to those of $p$, except that the point $p$ is replaced by the point $q$. Clearly $Y$ is no longer Hausdorff, but it is still $T_1$ and anticompact.

The first of **bof**’s examples has no isolated points, so we can do even better: it’s the real line with the topology generated by the usual open sets and the co-countable sets. Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ denote this space. Let $Y=X\times\{0,1\}$, and let

$$\mathscr{B}=\big\{(U\times\{0,1\})\setminus F:U\in\tau\text{ and }F\subseteq Y\text{ is finite}\big\}\;;$$

then $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for an anticompact $T_1$ topology on $Y$ such that for each $y\in Y$ there is a $y'\in Y$ such that $y$ and $y'$ do not have disjoint open nbhds: if $y=\langle x,i\rangle$, then $y'=\langle x,1-i\rangle$.

Comment: The first example is a special case of the following, with the same argument: The topological sum of any number of anticompact spaces is anticompact.