# first countable, anti compact which is not Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A space $X$ is called anti-compact if any compact subset of $X$ is finite. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/517419/12042), there are three anti compact Haudorff which is not discrete and in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1458282/anti-compact-space/1458398#1458398), **Brian M. Scott** has gave anti compact but not Haudorff. Since in **Brian M. Scott's** examples, the spaces are not first countable, so I am wondering whether is it true that every first countable anti compact space is always Hausdorff? Could some one prove it or give a counter example whenever it is not true.

Comment: You should always try some examples, first.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the indiscrete topology on two points . . .

---

Less stupidly: the topology on $\mathbb{N}$ where the open sets are exactly those of the form $\{x: x\le n\}$ for some $n$.