# Is there a connected $T_1$ anticompact topological space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

*[Now cross-posted to Mathoverflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435429)*

A topological space is a called [anticompact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409825) if all its compact subsets are finite.

> **Question 1:** Is there a (non-trivial) connected $T_1$ anticompact space?

Obviously the singleton and the empty space satisfy these properties.  So let's assume such a space $X$ has at least two points.  Here are some observations:

(1) $X$ must be infinite.  Because finite $T_1$ spaces are discrete, such a space would not be connected.

(2) $X$ cannot be compact.

(3) $X$ must be totally path disconnected, because anticompact $T_1$ spaces are totally path disconnected.  (The image of a continuous map $[0,1]\to X$ is compact, connected and $T_1$, hence finite and $T_1$, so it would be discrete, and connected. Thus it must a single point.)

(4) $X$ cannot be sequential, as a consequence of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4567778). In particular, $X$ cannot be first countable.

---

**Answer (from Ulli):** Yes.  Any uncountable set with the cocountable topology is connected and anticompact.  It is also $T_1$, but not $T_2$.

So updating the question:

> **Question 2:** Is there a (non-trivial) connected Hausdorff anticompact space?

---

I think the following would be an example.  Take $X=[0,1]$. Let $\tau_1$ be the usual Euclidean topology on $X$ and take on $X$ the topology $\tau$ generated by $\tau_1$ and the cocountable topology.  By using the Lindelof property for $\mathbb{R}$ it's not too difficult to show that the topology is described by
$$\tau=\{U\setminus A: U\in\tau_1 \text{ and } A\subseteq X \text { is countable}\}.$$

Every countable subset of $X$ is closed, and is discrete since all its subsets are also countable, hence closed.  So if $A$ is an infinite subset of $X$, it cannot be compact; otherwise a countably infinite subset of it would also be compact (as closed in a compact set) and discrete, which is impossible.  This shows that $X$ is anticompact.

$X$ is Hausdorff.

To show that $X$ is connected, suppose $X=Y\cup Z$ with $Y$ and $Z$ nonempty disjoint open sets.  Take a point $x\in Y$.  There is a Euclidean nbhd $U$ of $x$ such that $Y$ contains all the points of $U$ except countably many of them (where countable = finite or countably infinite).  Any point $z\in U\setminus Y$ would have to be contained in $Z$.  And since $Z$ is open in $X$, $U\cap Z$ would be a countable nbhd of $z$, which is impossible.  This shows that both $Y$ and $Z$ are open in the Euclidean topology.  Again that is impossible since $[0,1]$ is connected in its usual topology.

I would appreciate if you could confirm that the example above is correct.

---

This leads me to the revised question:

> **Question 3:** Is there a countably infinite connected $T_1$ (or $T_2$) anticompact space?

I can't find an example.  The Arens-Fort space or the Appert space are anticompact (and not first countable) but not connected.  Countably infinite connected examples that I know of, like the irrational slope topology or the Golomb space, are first countable, hence not anticompact.

Comment: Your uncountable example $X$ is NOT Hausdorff but it  IS $T_1.$

Comment: Just taking the cocountable topology on $\mathbb{R}$ (or $\omega_1$) is also anticompact, connected and T1 (but not Hausdorff).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: the example of the OP is finer than the euclidean topology, hence it *is* Hausdorff. Just taking the cocountable topology wouldn't be Hausdorff.

Comment: @Ulli I kind of knew that, but thanks for reminding me.  I guess the nice thing is it's a Hausdorff example (which should have been a better original question).  I'll update the post.  So the only thing not obvious is to find a countably infinite example (T_1 or T_2).

Comment: @Ulli Updated post

Comment: @Ulli. I was referring to the co-countable topology on [01] following Q2.

Comment: According to [space 63, item 9 in *Counterexamples*](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000055/properties/P000036) your X in Question 2 is connected. I think your proof for anticompact is also correct (item 7 in *Counterexamples* is exactly this as well, though they didn't track "anticompact") and will contribute it to pi-Base.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *partial* answer to question 3, namely an example of a connected, anticompact T1-topology on the (positive) integers:

Let  $\mathfrak{F}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ and $\tau := \mathfrak{F} \cup \{\emptyset\}$ the ultrafilter topology on $\mathbb{N}$.
Since $\mathfrak{F}$ is free, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{n\} \in \mathfrak{F}$, hence $\{n\}$ is closed. Thus, the topology is T1.

The intersection of any two non-empty, open sets is non-empty again. Hence the topology is connected.

It is anticompact:   
Let $A$ be an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Then there exists $U \in \mathfrak{F}$ such that $A \setminus U$ is infinite.  
[$A$ is the disjoint union of two infinite subsets $S, T$. If $S \in \mathfrak{F}$ or $T \in \mathfrak{F}$, we are done. Otherwise,
$\mathbb{N} \setminus S  \in \mathfrak{F}$ and
$\mathbb{N} \setminus T  \in \mathfrak{F}$.
Hence
$\mathbb{N} \setminus A =  \mathbb{N} \setminus (S \cup T) = (\mathbb{N} \setminus S) \cap (\mathbb{N} \setminus S) \in \mathfrak{F}$.] 
Now, $A \setminus U$ is discrete. 
[For any $x \in A \setminus U$,
$\{x\} =  (U \cup \{x\}) \cap (A \setminus U)$
is open in $A \setminus U$.] 
Furthermore, $A \setminus U \notin \mathfrak{F}$.
Hence its complement is open, hence $A \setminus U$ is closed in $\mathbb{N}$ and thus in $A$. Therefore $A$ cannot be compact.

Note:
Of course, this topology is far from being Hausdorff.

Comment: Very nice example for the $T_1$ case.

Comment: Talking about ultrafilters, there is the [Single ultrafilter topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000111/properties) = example #114 in "Counterexamples in Topology".  It is countable and $T_2$ and it seems the same arguments that you used can show it is anticompact.  But it is far from connected, as it's zero-dimensional.

Comment: [Gustin's sequence space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000122/properties) seems to be a candidate: it's countable, T2, and connected. Anti-compact is open in the pi-Base. EDIT: or not, it's first-countable, that's just not tracked.

Answer (score 1):

As answered in the [cross-post to mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435429), a paper by [T. Banakh and Y. Stelmakh](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.12579) provides examples of countably infinite connected Hausdorff anticompact spaces.  Their examples are even strongly rigid.